# Disable grid in chrome device emulation

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

I know this question may not fit well here but this really is driving me crazy for few hours now :( I use chrome to simulate how websites look on different mobile devices. I clicked something wrong that led to a grid with rulers to appear. I don't know WTF to do to disable this grid. This is the screenshot:

[image]

I uninstalled and reinstalled the browser and it returns back.
I reset the developer tools to default settings and it's still there.

This is really becoming a nightmare for me for few hours now. I want the regular emulation without these rulers and grid and top bar. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

There is a small blue button on the left of Elements which actually does the magic.

[image: it is blue because it is on]

Answer (score 1):

You didn't click anything wrong.  Your Chrome updated itself to 38.2125 and the emulator now has those attributes.  Further more, the touch function is broken.

To fix the problem, download the "Canary" version of Chrome.  You're still required to see the grid, but the screen is improved and easier to see your layout.  Also, the touch function is fixed.

Get Chrome Canary here: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html

Comment: Hey Don :) Thanks for the reply. It had nothing to do with the version as I have the latest version and  this problem happened suddenly when i was working. I clicked something that triggered this. I fixed it by totally removing the browser by removing all it's settings and configuration not just uninstall. Now I have the latest version with the simple interface :) I'm on a Mac and the latest version there is 37.0.2062.124. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: You may find the grid in your future.  Indeed, I use Win7 and have a higher-numbered version.  Glad you were able to fix it.  I don't like it either.  Even with Canary improvements it's not a nice as the older, simpler view.

Answer (score 0):

That button just enables/disables the emulator. The OP is looking for a way to disable the background grid while emulating mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to disable the multi-colored grid lines that show up as an overlay, check out the console dock on the bottom of dev tools. There is a tab labeled rendering and try disabling "Show composited layer borders". If you're still seeing the rulers, that setting is in the Settings (gear) of dev tools, there is an option under the Elements heading for "Show rulers".